# Xamarin: Unable to Load assembly XLabs.Forms.Control FileNotFoundException error

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use ImageButton control in my content page. I added the 'XLabs.Forms.Controls' package from nuget. But in my xaml it throws the FileNotFoundException error.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'XLabs.Forms.Controls' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

I have defined the namespace to my xaml as following:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had also faced this problem, I solved it with a trick of instantiating the class of control which is being used from `XLabs.Forms.Controls` package to my code behind of `xaml` as :

```
public HomePage : ContentPage
{
    ImageButton ib = new ImageButton();
    InitializeComponent ();
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too :) Thanks !!